# Email Workbooks based on Workbook name to different addresses

Tags: vba, excel, email

I have code that opens a dialog box that allows a user to select an Excel sheet, filters the country column (11), copies and pastes that country into a new workbook, names the new workbook after that country, repeats the action for the next country, saves and closes each Workbook.

Currently before it closes the workbook it sends the newly created workbooks to my email address.

I want if the workbook is named "Belgium" email to Jane.Doe@email.com, if the Workbook is named "Bulagria" email to John.Doe@Email.com and so on. Different countries get emailed to different addresses.

My Email CODE is here

```
Public Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'This example send the last saved version of the Activeworkbook
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "philip.connell@email.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = "Hi there"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        'You can add other files also like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

MAIN BODY OF CODE

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()

Dim my_FileName As Variant
Dim my_Workbook As Workbook

  MsgBox "Pick your CRO file" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

  my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

  If my_FileName <> False Then
    Set my_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=my_FileName)

    Call TestThis

    Call Filter(my_Workbook) '<--|Calls the Filter Code and executes

  End If
End Sub

Public Sub Filter(my_Workbook As Workbook)
  Dim rCountry As Range, helpCol As Range
  Dim wb As Workbook
  With my_Workbook.Sheets(1) '<--| refer to data worksheet
    With .UsedRange
      Set helpCol = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count) '<--| get a "helper" column just at the right of used range, it'll be used to store unique country names in
    End With

   With .Range("A1:Y" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| refer to its columns "A:Y" from row 1 to last non empty row of column "A"
            .Columns(11).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=helpCol, Unique:=True '<-- call AdvancedFilter on 11th column of the referenced range and store its unique values in "helper" column
            Set helpCol = Range(helpCol.Offset(1), helpCol.End(xlDown)) '<--| set range with unique names in (skip header row)
            For Each rCountry In helpCol '<--| iterate over unique country names range (skip header row)
                .AutoFilter 11, rCountry.Value2 '<--| filter data on country field (11th column) with current unique country name
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
                    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add '<--... add new Workbook
                        wb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\CONNELLP\Desktop\Claire Macro\CRO Countries\" & rCountry.Value2 '<--... saves the workbook after the country
                            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
                               ActiveSheet.Name = rCountry.Value2  '<--... rename it
                           .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header
                           Sheets(1).Range("A1:Y1").WrapText = False 'Takes the wrap text off
                           ActiveWindow.Zoom = 55 'Zooms out the window
                         Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit 'Autofits the column
                    ActiveWorkbook.Save '<--... saves and closes workbook
                    Call Mail_workbook_Outlook_1
                    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True '<--... saves and closes workbook
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter and show all rows back
    End With
    helpCol.Offset(-1).End(xlDown).Clear '<--| clear helper column (header included)
End Sub

Public Sub TestThis()
Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

With wks
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("A:K").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues
.Range("A:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = 65535
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub

Public Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'This example send the last saved version of the Activeworkbook
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "Philip.Connell@email.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = "Hi there"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        'You can add other files also like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Picture of Original 
[image]

Pic of Countries Sheet

[image]

Comment: where do you have the country-email correspondence stored? In some cells?

Comment: @user3598756: Hi ah OK so i need the email address stored somewhere like on another worksheet is this correct?

Comment: I have added pics for better understanding. Thank you again for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following these steps

- in `Public Sub Filter(my_Workbook As Workbook)`, add

  ```
  Dim outApp As Object '<-- declare the object where to store Outlook application reference
  Dim addrRng As Range
  ```

  between declarations
- in `Public Sub Filter(my_Workbook As Workbook)` add

  ```
  Set outApp = GetOutlook
  ```

  just before

  ```
  With my_Workbook.Sheets(1) '<--| refer to data worksheet
  ```
- in `Public Sub Filter(my_Workbook As Workbook)`, add

  ```
              Set addrRng = GetCountryAddressRange(.Parent.Parent.Worksheets("countries"), rCountry.Value2) '<-- try getting passed country name in worksheet "countries"
              If addrRng Is Nothing Then '<--| if country not found, inform the user
                  MsgBox "Sorry, " & rCountry.Value2 & " not found in worksheet 'countries'" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                  & "no mail will be sent", vbInformation
              Else '<--| if  found, send the email
                  Call Mail_workbook_Outlook_1(outApp, addrRng)
              End If
  ```

  between

  ```
  ActiveWorkbook.Save '<--... saves and closes workbook
  ```

  and

  ```
  wb.Close SaveChanges:=True '<--... saves and closes workbook
  ```
- in `Public Sub Filter(my_Workbook As Workbook)`, add

  ```
  outApp.Quit '<-- close outlook
  Set outApp = Nothing
  ```

  just before `End Sub`
- modify `Mail_workbook_Outlook_1` as follows

  ```
  Public Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1(outApp As Object, addrRng As Range)

      With outApp.CreateItem(0)
          .to = addrRng.text '<-- email in found cell content
          .CC = ""
          .BCC = ""
          .Subject = addrRng.Offset(, 1).text '<-- subject in cell one column right of found one
          .Body = addrRng.Offset(, 2).text '<-- subject in cell two column right of found one
          .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
          'You can add other files also like this
          '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
          .Send   'or use .Display
      End With
  End Sub
  ```
- add the following functions in any module

  ```
  Function GetCountryAddressRange(ws As Worksheet, name As String) As Range
      Dim f As Range
      With ws
          Set f = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Find(what:=name, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
      End With
      If Not f Is Nothing Then Set GetCountryAddressRange = f.Offset(, 1)
  End Function


  Function GetOutlook() As Object
      Set GetOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
      If GetOutlook Is Nothing Then Set GetOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  End Function
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much once again of your help. As always it is greatly appreciated. Unfortunately I am getting a 'Run Time Error 9 Subscript Out of Range' On this line `Set addrRng = GetCountryAddressRange(.Parent.Parent.Worksheets("countries"), rCountry.Value2) '<-- try getting passed country name in worksheet "countries"` any help to get passed this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming that there's a "countries" worksheet in the workbook you opened

Comment: Yes I have a worksheet named "countries" in my Workbook.

Comment: is the "countries" worksheet in the very same workbook you open in `Open_Workbook_Dialog()`. Or is it in the workbook where the macro resides in?

Comment: The Countries Worksheet is in the Workbook that I open in `Open_Workbook_Dialog()`

Comment: then place `MsgBox .Parent.Parent.name` right before `GetCountryAddressRange(.Parent.Parent.Worksheets("countries"‌​), rCountry.Value2)` run the macro and see what that message box tells you

Comment: Hi so I changed the line that was bugging to `Set addrRng = GetCountryAddressRange(.Parent.Parent.Worksheets(1), rCountry.Value2) '<-- try getting passed country name in worksheet "countries"` now I am getting the POP UP telling me that 'Belgium' Is not in the Countries work sheet.

Comment: do what I asked you the comment before. In the meanwhile, from your last comment I'd say there's no "countries" worksheet in the `.Parent.Parent` workbook (which should be the one you opened, but we'll see as soon as you get beck with the answer to my last question)

Comment: What I have done is changed `Worksheets("countries")` to `Worksheets(1)` Now I get the POP UP

Comment: please do what I asked you for

Comment: No Problem. So now have this line `MsgBox .Parent.Parent.name = GetCountryAddressRange(.Parent.Parent.Worksheets("countries"), rCountry.Value2)`  in the code. Sorry if this is incorrect. But the code is now  falling down @ `Set GetOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")`

Comment: NO. the statement `MsgBox .Parent.Parent.name` must be _alone_ and precede `Set addrRng = GetCountryAddressRange(.Parent.Parent.Worksheets("countries"), rCountry.Value2)` one. As to your last error I suggest you to close both Excel and Outlook, and then start it all over again

Comment: Ok having put `MsgBox .Parent.Parent.name`Alone and preceding the line in question. I am now getting a pop up that states Template.xls Thank you for your continued support and assistance it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127824/discussion-between-user3598756-and-philip-connell).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be using a "select case" statement and passing the return value to Mail_workbook_Outlook_1 as parameter.

```
Function GetMailAddress(country as string) as string
    Select Case country
        Case country1 GetMailAddress = address1
        Case country2 GetMailAddress = address2
        Case else GetMailAddress = address3
    End Select
End Function
```

Of course, it would make sense to store the information somewhere where it is easier to modify, a Countries-Sheet in your master-file / addin maybe.

```
Function GetMailAddress(country as string) as string
    dim countriesSheet as worksheet
    set countriesSheet = Sheets("Countries")
    dim i as long
    do while countriesSheet.cells(i,1) <> ""
        if countriesSheet.cells(i,1) = country then
          GetMailAddress = countriesSheet.cells(i,2)
          exit function
        end if
        i = i+1

    loop
    GetMailAddress = "yourdefaultaddress"
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It is greatly appreciated. The first piece of code. I have never inserted a function into any code before. Where would I place it in my existing code

Comment: I have added pics for better understanding. Thank you again for the help

Comment: Just place it underneath your Sub, it is basically the same structure as a Sub, except that it returns a value (by assigning a value to the function name).

Comment: @ Matthias: Thank you for the help. I have placed it under my Sub. Do I now have to call this function and if so where do I place it to call it correctly. Again thank you for the help.

Comment: Replace `Call Mail_workbook_Outlook_1` with `Call Mail_workbook_Outlook_1(GetMailAddress( rCountry.Value2))`, if rCountry.Value2 contains the current country name.

Comment: I changed what you asked but now I get a compile error 'Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment' SO i need to change the heading of the Outlook sub further below in the code?

Comment: Ah sure :) Adapt your Mail_workbook_Outlook_1 Sub: `Public Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1(address as string)` and in the body `With OutMail     .to = address`

Comment: Thank you again for the help. It is greatly appreciated. I have made the changes but I now get another error. `By ref argument type Mismatch` in `Call Mail_workbook_Outlook_1(address)` address is highlighted blue and `Public Sub Filter(my_Workbook As Workbook)` is in yellow. again thank you for the help.

Comment: Hm, `Call Mail_workbook_Outlook_1(GetMailAddress( rCountry.Value2))` should be used to invoke the GetMailAddress-Function. The address-string is only used internally in the  Mail_workbook_Outlook_1-Method. Maybe its easier if you update your first post to show the current Subs/Functions.